# pyautogui.click doesn't click on the target

Tags: python, pyautogui

Here's my code:

```
import pyautogui

button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('pop.png')
button7location

button7x, button7y = pyautogui.center(button7location)
button7x, button7y

pyautogui.click(button7x, button7y)
```

It's the same code from the official documentation. When the script is run, the screenshot is located, but the click is performed away from the actual button.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

After the script is run the mouse shifts to and click on the right edge of the screen, it's pretty close to the target.

Comment: Where do you expect your mouse click to be performed? Try printing the coordinates of the located window as well as the center of it.

Comment: @VasilisG. I used  `print(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.png'))` to print the coordinates of the button 4 on calculator and got `(2858, 1632, 148, 120)`.  `print(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('image.png'))` gave me `(2932, 1692)` but it's not clicking on the button, it's clicking a little to the right and bottom of it.

Comment: Try making adjustments such as `button7x -= 74` and `button7y -= 60`, where `74` and `60` are half of width and height of the button respectively.

Comment: @VasilisG. I made some adjustments and it DID click on 4, but it's only working when the calculator is at the extreme right of the screen, if I move the calculator anywhere else, I get the offset again.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to replace `74` with `button7location[2] // 2` and `64` with `button7location[3] // 2`, as a way to generalize the adjustments.